# Error passing managedObjectContext between classes for core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5

I'm following along with this tutorial: http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/ and I am getting this error trying to pass a managedObjectContext between classes:

```
2012-04-23 09:53:13.969 PictureList[10287:fb03] -[UINavigationController    setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d20a80
2012-04-23 09:53:13.992 PictureList[10287:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught  exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController    setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d20a80'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16ab022 0x183ccd6 0x16accbd 0x1611ed0 0x1611cb2 0x1c05 0x14386 0x15274 0x24183 0x24c38    0x18634 0x1595ef5 0x167f195 0x15e3ff2 0x15e28da 0x15e1d84 0x15e1c9b 0x14c65 0x16626 0x1afd    0x1a65)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

The error seems kind of vague but I suspect that the UINavigationController is the cause of this problem. The app crashes immediately when I run it.

Here is the code for my Appdelegate.m where I'm trying to pass the Context to my initial controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    // Pass the managed object context to the root view controller (the login view)
    LoginViewController *rootView = (LoginViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    rootView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    ....
    }
return YES;
}
```

And then I'm trying to pass from my LoginViewController to the next class through a segue.
LoginViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    PictureListMainTable *piclist = (PictureListMainTable *)[[navController viewControllers] lastObject];
    piclist.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
}
```

Anther thing I tried was to pass the context along to the UINavigationController:

```
// This code was customized to handle the navigation controller
// Pass the managed object context to the root view controller (the login view)
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
LoginViewController *rootView = (LoginViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
rootView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Using this approach I was at least able to get the app to load to the login screen, but when I attempted to segue the app would crash. How can I fix this problem?

Edit: Ok, found the problem. In the tutorial I was undre the impression that the navigation was embedded before the login the login controller, but the navigation controller actually goes in between the LoginViewController and PictureListMainTable.

Comment: Can you write your solution as an answer below? You can then accept it and the question will be complete (something, something, something, Dark Side...) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems quite specific I would say: at some point in your app is the line `[navController setManagedObjectContext: ...]`, coded either explicitly, or implicitly by setting the `managedObjectContext` property of a `UINavigationController` instance or subclass (which you do).

The error is saying that `UINavigationController` doesn't have a `setManagedObjectContext:` method. It's likely you are using the wrong settings in an `@property` declaration in the .h, missing a more permissive `@property` line in your .m's interface, or missing an `@synthesize` directive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a property in that LoginViewController class:

In LoginViewController.h :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
```

In LoginViewController.m :

```
@synthesize context;
```

Then in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
// Pass the managed object context to the root view controller (the login view)
LoginViewController *rootView = (LoginViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
rootView.context= self.managedObjectContext;
```